# How to remove certain words from text while keeping punctuation marks

Tags: python, text, split

I have the following code that removes Bangla words from given text. It can remove listed words from text successfully, but it fails to remove a word with punctuation. For example, here, from input text "বিশ্বের তথা দূষিত না বায়ুর না, শহরের না।", it can remove, "তথা" and "না"(since listed in word_list) but it can't remove না with punctuations( "না," and "না।" ) . I want to remove words with punctuations as well but keeping the punctuations. Please see the current and expected output below. Thanks a lot. Punctuation list=[,।?]

```
word_list = {'নিজের', 'তথা', 'না'}
def remove_w(text):
    return ' '.join(w for w in text.split() if w not in word_list)
remove_w('বিশ্বের তথা দূষিত না বায়ুর না, শহরের না।')
```

> Current Output::: 'বিশ্বের দূষিত বায়ুর না, শহরের না।'

> Expected Output::: 'বিশ্বের দূষিত বায়ুর, শহরের।'

Comment: Would the `re` package and `re.split("\W", text)` help here? Sorry I can't really tell.

Comment: @JonSG not working. Would you suggest anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code does what you desire:

```python
import re

word_list = {'নিজের', 'তথা', 'না'}
def remove_w(text):
    result = ''.join(w for w in re.split(r'([ ,।\?])', text) if w not in word_list)
    # sanitize the result:
    result = re.sub(r' +([,।\?])', r'\1', result)
    result = re.sub(r' +', r' ', result)
    return result

remove_w('বিশ্বের তথা দূষিত না বায়ুর না, শহরের না।')
# 'বিশ্বের দূষিত বায়ুর, শহরের।'
```

The parentheses within `r'([ ,।\?])'` [serve to keep the delimiters in the result](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split):

> `re.split(pattern, string)` [simplified: default arguments omitted]
> If capturing parentheses are used in *pattern*, then the text of all groups in the pattern [is] also returned as part of the resulting list.

Note that we need manual sanitization of the result:

- spaces before punctuation will be removed
- multiple successive spaces are merged into a single space

I would also like to draw other readers' attention to the fact that `।` is a Bengali punctuation mark (দাঁড়ি, in English commonly referred to as *daṇḍa*), not an ASCII vertical bar `|`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that you have to use a more complex split operation like

```
  from re import compile

  reSeparator = compile("[ ,]+")

  if __name__ == "__main__":
      print(reSeparator.split("a,  b,, c "))
```

(I can't imagine, what other punctuation marks apply to that character set.) Otherwise "a," is of course different from "a", so `in word_list` will not return true. Note that trailing separators will give an empty element.

Comment: Could you write a runnable code with that please? I am getting errors. Thanks a lot.